# What Alloc API may call VirtualAlloc/reserve memory internally?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll, virtual-memory

I am debugging a potential memory leak problem in a debug DLL.

The case is that process run a sub-test which loads/unloads a DLL dynamically, during the test a lot of memory is reserved and committed(1.3GB). After test is finished and DLL unloaded, still massive amount of memory remains reserved(1.2GB).

Reason why I said this reserved memory is allocated by DLL is that if I use a release DLL(nothing else changed, same test), reserved memory is ~300MB, so all the additional reserved memory must be allocated in debug DLL.

Looks like a lot of memory is committed during test but decommit(not release to free status) after test. So I want to track who reserve/decommit that large memory. But in the source code, there is no VirtualAlloc called, so questions are:

1. Is VirtualAlloc the only way to reserve memory?
2. If not, what other API can do that? If is, what other API will internally call VirtualAlloc? Quite some people online says HeapAlloc will internally call VirtualAlloc? How does it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Parts of this are purely implementation detail, and not things that your application should rely on, so take them only for informational purposes, not as official documentation or contract of any kind. That said, there is some value in understanding how things are implemented under the hood, if only for debugging purposes.]*

Yes, the VirtualAlloc() function is the workhorse function for memory allocation in Windows. It is a low-level function, one that the operating system makes available to you if you need its features, but also one that the system uses internally. (To be precise, it probably doesn't call VirtualAlloc() directly, but rather an even lower level function that VirtualAlloc() also calls down to, like NtAllocateVirtualMemory(), but that's just semantics and doesn't change the observable behavior.)

Therefore, HeapAlloc() is built on top of VirtualAlloc(), as are GlobalAlloc() and LocalAlloc() (although the latter two became obsolete in 32-bit Windows and should basically never be used by applications—prefer explicitly calling HeapAlloc()).

Of course, HeapAlloc() is not just a simple wrapper around VirtualAlloc(). It adds some logic of its own. VirtualAlloc() always allocates memory in large chunks, defined by the system's allocation granularity, which is hardware-specific (retrievable by calling GetSystemInfo() and reading the value of `SYSTEM_INFO.dwAllocationGranularity`). HeapAlloc() allows you to allocate smaller chunks of memory at whatever granularity you need, which is much more suitable for typical application programming. Internally, HeapAlloc() handles calling VirtualAlloc() to obtain a large chunk, and then divvying it up as needed. This not only presents a simpler API, but is also more efficient.

Note that the memory allocation functions provided by the C runtime library (CRT)—namely, C's malloc() and C++'s new operator—are a higher level yet. These are built on top of HeapAlloc() (at least in Microsoft's implementation of the CRT). Internally, they allocate a sizable chunk of memory that basically serves as a "master" block of memory for your application, and then divvy it up into smaller blocks upon request. As you free/delete those individual blocks, they are returned to the pool. Once again, this extra layer provides a simplified interface (and in particular, the ability to write platform-independent code), as well as increased efficiency in the general case.

Memory-mapped files and other functionality provided by various OS APIs is also built upon the virtual memory subsystem, and therefore internally calls VirtualAlloc() (or a lower-level equivalent).

So yes, fundamentally, the lowest level memory allocation routine for a normal Windows application is VirtualAlloc(). But that doesn't mean it is the workhorse function that you should generally use for memory allocation. Only call VirtualAlloc() if you actually need its additional features. Otherwise, either use your standard library's memory allocation routines, or if you have some compelling reason to avoid them (like not linking to the CRT or creating your own custom memory pool), call HeapAlloc().

Note also that you must always free/release memory using the corresponding mechanism to the one you used to allocate the memory. Just because all memory allocation functions ultimately call VirtualAlloc() does *not* mean that you can free that memory by calling VirtualFree(). As discussed above, these other functions implement additional logic on top of VirtualAlloc(), and thus require that you call their own routines to free the memory. Only call VirtualFree() if you allocated the memory yourself via a call to VirtualAlloc(). If the memory was allocated with HeapAlloc(), call HeapFree(). For malloc(), call free(); for new, call delete.

---

As for the specific scenario described in your question, it is unclear to me why you are worrying about this. It is important to keep in mind the distinction between *reserved* memory and *committed* memory. Reserved simply means that this particular block in the address space has been reserved for use by the process. Reserved blocks cannot be used. In order to use a block of memory, it must be committed, which refers to the process of allocating a backing store for the memory, either in the page file or in physical memory. This is also sometimes known as *mapping*. Reserving and committing can be done as two separate steps, or they can be done at the same time. For example, you might want to reserve a contiguous address space for future use, but you don't actually need it yet, so you don't commit it. Memory that has been reserved but not committed is not actually allocated.

In fact, all of this reserved memory may not be a leak at all. A rather common strategy used in debugging is to reserve a specific range of memory addresses, without committing them, to trap attempts to access memory within this range with an "access violation" exception. The fact that your DLL is not making these large reservations when compiled in Release mode suggests that, indeed, this may be a debugging strategy. And it also suggests a better way of determining the source: rather than scanning through your code looking for all of the memory-allocation routines, scan your code looking for the conditional code that depends upon the build configuration. If you're doing something different when `DEBUG` or `_DEBUG` is defined, then that is probably where the magic is happening.

Another possible explanation is the CRT's implementation of malloc() or new. When you allocate a small chunk of memory (say, a few KB), the CRT will actually reserve a much larger block but only commit a chunk of the requested size. When you subsequently free/delete that small chunk of memory, it will be decommitted, but the larger block will not be released back to the OS. The reason for this is to allow future calls to malloc/new to re-use that reserved block of memory. If a subsequent request is for a larger block than can be satisfied by the currently reserved address space, it will reserve additional address space. If, in debugging builds, you are repeatedly allocating and freeing increasingly large chunks of memory, what you're seeing may be the result of memory fragmentation. But this is really not a problem, aside from a minor performance hit, which is really not worth worrying about in debugging builds.

Comment: Incredibly clear explanation, great thank. I have a final question: so here can we say "a large amount of reserved memory is not a memory leak"? Or just "it mostly shouldn't be a memory leak". And is there a concept of "reserved memory leak?"

Comment: A memory leak is where you lose the ability to free memory that you have allocated. Regardless of whether that memory is committed or reserved, if you lose the ability to uncommit or unreserve it, you have a leak. Now, the operating system will clean up after your process after it exists, so in practice, a leak only matters for the lifetime of an application. But it's still a memory leak if you reserve a bunch of memory and then are never able to release it. I'm not sure why it wouldn't be. @michael

Comment: What I'm saying above in the final paragraphs are that there are reasons why you might end up with a lot of reserved memory but still not have a memory leak in your code. One of the more likely reasons is because of the implementation of the C runtime library's memory allocation routines. They aren't actually leaking that memory, because they still maintain the ability to release it if they wanted to, they just are not programmed to do so.